# What is the name of the default seaborn color palette?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

From the top of https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html:

[image]

But what is the default one called? That is, how do I invoke it in `sns.set_palette()` if I changed to a different palette and want to revert to the default? I also couldn't find an answer at https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.color_palette.html.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By default seaborn uses the matplotlib default colors. If you have not changed the default matplotlib parameters, this would be the colors from the `"tab10"` colormap.

```
sns.set_palette("tab10")
```

If however you have set some style beforehands, e.g. using `sns.set()`, this would set the palette to `"deep"`. Hence you would get this back using

```
sns.set_palette("deep")
```

Comment: The bolded section here suggested to me that it's not just the matplotlib defaults: "When importing seaborn, the default color cycle is changed to a set of six colors that evoke the standard matplotlib color cycle **while aiming to be a bit more pleasing to look at.**"

Comment: Yes, but this change is applied *after* setting the colors.